# Equation no not showing in align environment

Tags: equations, align

I am preparing a document that has only one equation. I tried to write it using both the `align` and `equation` environment. But surprisingly, none worked for me. When I used the `align` environment, no equation no was shown. When I used the `equation` environment, the equation no was 0 (zero).

[image: No equation no shown]
No equation no is shown with the `align` environment

[image: Equation no is set as zero with equation environment]
Equation no is set to zero with `equation` environment

I have tried writing only the equation with all used packages in a separate tex file and that worked as expected. So, I couldn't generate a minimal example. As my whole code is too large to share here, I am sharing an overleaf link of the code.The link is: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gsnqfcjdhrfn

The equation is between 117 and 120 lines (at the bottom of the code). How can this problem be solved?

Edit: As I didn't know exactly what was causing the problem, I couldn't add any code here. But as @campa said in a comment, without a code this question will be pointless in the future. Also, @daleif pointed out the problem in the code. So, I am adding a minimal working example here.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
           blah blah blah
    \end{titlepage}
    \nonumber
    blah blah blah

    The swing equation of a power system is:
    \begin{align}
         2\times H \times f \times \frac{df}{dt} = P_m - P_e    
         \label{eqn1}
    \end{align}
    where $f$ is the system frequency, $H$ is the inertia constant, 
    $t$ denotes time, $P_m$ is the input mechanical power and $P_e$ 
    is the output electrical power.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the code *here*. Links to external pages are pointless as the question will become useless when the link disappears.

Comment: @campa I am not understanding why it's happening and thus can't exactly say which part is relevant. That's why I haven't added the code here.

Comment: What is that nonumber doing right after the title page? Additionally you're making a lit of mistakes in that code.

Comment: @daleif Ooops! Thanks. I couldn't find it for more than two hours. The error is too silly. Should I remove this question? And also can you please say, what other mistakes I have done?

Comment: Since you're not providing code here (always preferred as links rot over time) your question might not be useful to others. But please look up a good intro to larex as you're making a lot of mistakes in that code.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion. I will provide a mwe to make it bit more useful.

Comment: @daleif oops I hadn't read the comment thread, sorry:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no alignment here so you should use `equation` not `align` but the reason that you have no number is that you have used

```
   \nonumber
```

While it gives no error there, that command is completely mis-placed it should only be used inside an equation where it will suppress the number for that equation only.

Comment: Possibly `\nonumber` might check for not being in a display…